# copy multiple 1D matrix into one large 1D matrix in Emgucv or Opencv

Tags: opencv, matrix, emgucv

I was trying to create a large Matrix contain rows images of tablets to use PCA function in Emgucv.
I was success in reshaping the tablet image (let say MxN) to a matrix ( 1 row,MxN column).Now I want to copy it to row i of the large Matrix ( k row, MxN column).Here is my code:

```
        Matrix<byte> largeMatrix= new  Matrix<byte> (k,M*N);
        Matrix<byte> temp = new Matrix<byte>(M,N);    //tablet image
        Matrix<byte> temp1 = new Matrix<byte>(1,M*N); //tablet image after reshaping into 1 row

        CvInvoke.cvConvert(src.Copy(),temp);
        CvInvoke.cvReshape(temp, temp1, 0, 1);
        //Written in C# using Emgucv
```

How to copy temp1 into exactly row i of matrix largeMatrix in Emgucv ( or Opencv ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy. I'm sorry I only have C++ code for you though.

```
cv::Mat dest; // size NxM (rowsxcols)
cv::Mat src; // size N
cv::Mat row(dest.row(i));
src.copyTo(row);
```

Now what is happening here?
The Mat `row` is a matrix header that wraps exactly the row `i` of `dest`. It does not create a copy but simply gives a different view of the same data. Then, the `copyTo()` method actually copies the data between two matrices.

It is important here to not write `row = src`. That would only change the header of `row`, not the data it points to.